# Highlighting Menu Best Practice

Tags: javascript, html, css

Functional Requirement:

*Current page must be highlighted

My menu is a list, so I added a class to a  tag, and used a CSS selector to style it differently.

```
    ul ul a.basic { /* Sub-menu stuff */
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: orange; /* Color of Home1-2-3 Background*/
}

ul ul a { /* Sub-menu stuff */
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: green; /* Color of Home1-2-3 Background*/
}
```

The current active menu item has a class "basic". I put the CSS code for .basic first, so it is overriden and becomes orange.

Is there a better / more efficient / ideal way to do this? What about through the use of javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: Add class 'active' instead of 'basic' first and match the browser url with menu link url to add class active by jquery.

Answer (score 1):

If you reload page on click of menu item then no need to use JavaScript just put mechanism of `.active` class in your code.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu{
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu li {
  float: left;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  list-style: outside none none;
}
.menu li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px; 
  display: block;
}
.menu li.active a{
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">OUR SERVICE</a></li>
</ul>
```